# xslt 1.0 groupby with a nested structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given a structure which looks like:

```
<feed>
    <entry>
        <summary>lorem ipsum 1</summary>
        <updated>2013-11-20T18:40:00Z</updated>
        <author>Jon</author>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <summary>lorem ipsum 2</summary>
        <updated>2013-11-19T19:40:00Z</updated>
        <author>Jon</author>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <summary>lorem ipsum 3</summary>
        <updated>2013-11-19T23:40:00Z</updated>
        <author>Rebecca</author>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <summary>lorem ipsum 4</summary>
        <updated>2013-11-18T05:40:00Z</updated>
        <author>Paul</author>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to create an XSLT which has an ouput similar to this structure (names are not important here.)

```
<blah>
    <today>
        <date>2013-11-20</date>
        <post>
            <summary>lorem ipsum 1</summary>
            <updated>2013-11-20T18:40:00Z</updated>
            <author>Jon</author>
        </post>
    </today>

    <today>
        <date>2013-11-19</date>
        <post>
            <summary>lorem ipsum 2</summary>
            <updated>2013-11-19T19:40:00Z</updated>
            <author>Jon</author>
        </post>
        <post>
            <summary>lorem ipsum 3</summary>
            <updated>2013-11-19T23:40:00Z</updated>
            <author>Rebecca</author>
        </post>
    </today>

    <today>
        <date>2013-11-18</date>
        <post>
            <summary>lorem ipsum 4</summary>
            <updated>2013-11-18T05:40:00Z</updated>
            <author>Paul</author>
        </post>
    </today>
</blah>
```

I understood that I should probably use one of the [methods defined for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/index.xml), but I haven't figured it out yet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="groupbydate" match="entry" use="updated"/>

    <xsl:template match="feed">
        <blah>
          <xsl:apply-templates
                select="entry[
                    generate-id() 
                    = generate-id(key('groupbydate', updated)[1])]" />
        </blah>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <!-- GET the date -->
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring(updated,1,10)"/>
        <today>
            <date><xsl:value-of select="$date"/></date>
        </today>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::entry[substring(updated,1,10) = $date]">
            <post>
                <xsl:copy-of select="entry"/>
            </post>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your key as

```
<xsl:key name="groupbydate" match="entry" use="substring-before(updated, 'T')"/>
```

then you need to use it e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="feed">
    <blah>
      <xsl:apply-templates
            select="entry[
                generate-id() 
                = generate-id(key('groupbydate', substring-before(updated, 'T'))[1])]" />
    </blah>
</xsl:template>
```

then you process each first item in the group with

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
  <today>
    <date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(updated, 'T')"/></date>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupbydate', substring-before(updated, 'T'))" mode="entry"/>
  </today>
</xsl:template>
```

and the items in each group with

```
<xsl:template match="entry" mode="entry">
  <post>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </post>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Both. Thank you very much, because it helped me to understand and solved my issue. Deeply appreciate.